# Python - Extracting inner most lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just started toying around with Python so please bear with me :)

Assume the following list which contains nested lists:

```
[[[[[1, 3, 4, 5]], [1, 3, 8]], [[1, 7, 8]]], [[[6, 7, 8]]], [9]]
```

In a different representation:

```
[
    [
        [
            [
                [1, 3, 4, 5]
            ], 
            [1, 3, 8]
        ], 
        [
            [1, 7, 8]
        ]
    ], 
    [
        [
            [6, 7, 8]
        ]
    ], 
    [9]
]
```

How would you go about extracting those inner lists so that a result with the following form would be returned:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 8], [1, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT (Thanks @falsetru):**

Empty inner-list or mixed type lists will never be part of the input.

Comment: What should be returned for `[[[[[1, 3, 4, 5]], [1, 3, 8]], [[1, 7, 8]]], [[[6, 7, 8]]], [9, [10]]]` and `[[[[[1, 3, 4, 5]], [1, 3, 8]], [[1, 7, 8]]], [[[6, 7, 8]]], []]`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question:
An empty list or a list with mixed type of items will never be part of the input

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This seems to work, assuming no 'mixed' lists like `[1,2,[3]]`:

```
def get_inner(nested):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in nested):
        for x in nested:
            for y in get_inner(x):
                yield y
    else:
        yield nested
```

Output of `list(get_inner(nested_list))`:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 8], [1, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Or even shorter, without generators, using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to combine the resulting lists:

```
def get_inner(nested):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in nested):
        return sum(map(get_inner, nested), [])
    return [nested]
```

Answer (score 13):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

def get_inner_lists(xs):
    if isinstance(xs[0], list): # OR all(isinstance(x, list) for x in xs)
        return chain.from_iterable(map(get_inner_lists, xs))
    return xs,
```

used `isinstance(xs[0], list)` instead of `all(isinstance(x, list) for x in xs)`, because there's no mixed list / empty inner list.

---

```
>>> list(get_inner_lists([[[[[1, 3, 4, 5]], [1, 3, 8]], [[1, 7, 8]]], [[[6, 7, 8]]], [9]]))
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 8], [1, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 5):

More efficient than recursion:

```
result = []
while lst:
    l = lst.pop(0)
    if type(l[0]) == list:
        lst += [sublst for sublst in l if sublst] # skip empty lists []
    else:
        result.insert(0, l)
```

Comment: Deleting the first item from list, Inserting into the beginning of the list take O(n) time. Using [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) could improves the speed. See http://ideone.com/RFGhnh

Comment: If you claim that your solution is more efficient than other solutions, please attach benchmarks for small and large input. See falsetru's comment why it is slow.