# Flattern one nested element in a list in python

Tags: python, list, flatten

for a nested list like this

```
alist = [[[1],[2],[3]],[1,2]]
```

how to flattern the first element so it becomes this?

```
[[1],[2],[3],[1,2]]
```

I tried the two flatten loops but it also flattened other elements

```
[item for sublist in alist for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are only interested in the first element? Is it because the sub-elements are also lists?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495848/python-extracting-inner-most-lists

Comment: coz i want each element to be a list, but not nested list.

Comment: @Sajin exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator function as below:

```
In [17]: def flatten(iterable):
             for sub in iterable:
                if isinstance(sub[0], list):
                  yield from sub
                else:
                  yield sub
   ....:                 

In [18]: list(flatten(alist))
Out[18]: [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2]]
```

But note that since we are checking the type of the first element in sub list to decide whether to flatten or not, this will work only if you want to flatten those sub lists that all of their items are list. Nevertheless, if you want it to handle all the cases you might want to check if there's any list inside the sub list (probably using `any()`).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
out = alist[0] + alist[1:]
print (out)
[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: I understand it is a good workaround but there may be many nested lists inside the list and solution from @Sajin's link seems more comprehensive

Comment: Yes, but then is necessary change question ;) - but then it is dupe, so maybe the best remove it?

Comment: true I think so, but the delete button is not working from my side. Do you mind?

Comment: OK, the best is not delete if not clearly dupe. But I am thinking about advantage of accepted answer - is possible first elemnent is not list? Because if not, then generator solution is a bit overcomplicated. Or something missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
def unlist_nested(L):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in L):
        return sum(map(get_inner, L), [])
    return [L]

alist = [[[1],[2],[3]],[1,2]]

unlist_nested(alist)
>>>[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: This is almost the worst way to solve this problem. Also, never use `sum` for flattening iterables it's *Shlemiel the painter*s' algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the nested list in `head` and `tail`, and sum them:

```
>>> alist = [[[1],[2],[3]],[1,2]]
>>> head, *tail = alist
>>> head + tail
[[1], [2], [3], [1, 2]]
```

If you want to further flatten the list:

```
>>> [x for l in (head + tail) for x in l]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

If you want to flatten the two first lists:

```
>>> alist = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[4], [5], [6]], [1,2]]
>>> head1, head2, *tail = alist
>>> head1 + head2 + tail
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [1, 2]]
```